# Android : How to get whether Bluetooth Device PC or Mobile?

Tags: android, bluetooth, mac-address, android-bluetooth

I want to to judge whether the particular device is Mobile device or PC/Laptop on the basis of its MAC Address or using standard API ?
Any Suggestions ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [getBluetoothClass](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getBluetoothClass%28%29). If connected device is smart phone then it will return [PHONE_SMART](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html#PHONE_SMART) value,
If connected deviceis computer desktop then it will return [COMPUTER_DESKTOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html#COMPUTER_DESKTOP)
And if connected device is laptop then it will return  [COMPUTER_LAPTOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html#COMPUTER_LAPTOP).

Hope it will helpful for you.